# Allow soft placement in tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I just upgraded from tf 1.1 to tf 1.4 for python 2.7 and I got the following problem:

I have a graph which I am putting all its OPs in the specific device by using tf.device('device') command. But, one of the OPs is only allowed to be in CPU device, so I am using allow_soft_placement=True and it was working correctly in tf 1.1 (it put only the OPs without GPU implementation in CPU and other OPs in GPU). But now (in tf1.4) when I am running my network it is putting all the OPs in the CPU (not just the one which has not GPU implementation).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some code? In particular the `tf.device('device')` statement.

Comment: I just reinstalled the tf again (instead of upgrading) and now it is working properly! and I have no idea why!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error probably occurs because you are using python 2.7. Where as tensorflow is for use with python 3.5 and python 3.6

Comment: Really?! Look at the following link. Tf is designed for both python 2 and 3 .https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux. Also, as I mentioned the problem is in tf1.4.